# Java - Is calling sort() upon an already sorted list an O(1) operation?

Tags: java, sorting

Does the `Collections.sort(list)` check if the `list` is already sorted or is it maybe O(1) for some other reason?
Or, is it a good idea to have a flag *sorted* and set it to `true`/`false` upon calling `sort()`/adding an element to the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How can you determine if any list is sorted without looking at it? It wont be `O(1)`. Determining if a list is sorted takes at least `O(n)`.

That would mean If `Collections.sort`did bother to check if a list was sorted first each sorting operation would take an average of `O(n) + O(n log n)`.

Comment: strictly speaking, O(1) does not mean 1 index :)

Comment: And `O(n) + O(n log n)` is the same as `O(n log n)` :)

Answer (score 8):

As a matter of fact with Java7, Java has switched from mergesort to [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (named after python dev Tim Peters who implemented it for cpython first) for some sorting tasks.

While it's not O(1), sorting an already sorted, or partially sorted list with TimSort is quite more efficient than sorting a completely random data set (for the later there's no way to be more efficient than `O(n log n)` for comparison sorts, that's not true for not random data).

Comment: Ok, but the probability that the person who asked is using Java 7 is quite low (some say 18% http://blog.jelastic.com/2011/12/07/java-7-adoption-grows-to-18-percent/)

Comment: @vitalik The probability that future readers will be using Java 7 or later can only increase from there. SO is intended as an archive of information, not a forum.

Comment: @EJP Considering that vitalik didn't downvote my post when he posted that comment, did you unintentionally misclick? Otherwise I'm quite surprised that anyone would downvote my post. b2t: I think as long as I explicitly mention that this is only true for Java7+ how many people are using whatever version isn't too important - 18% are still quite a lot of people.

Comment: The first comment looks so funny yet so obsolete in 2017 :)

Comment: @ilyailya Dunno - 18% Java 7 actually seems quite realistic these days ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way it's O(1), you can't check if the collection is sorted faster than O(n). Having a flag should be fine, but hard to say for sure without knowing what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, sorting an already sorted list doesn't make it faster (except simple sorts like bubble sort) In some cases pre-sorted is slower.

In the case of Collections.sort(), it is no faster to sort a sorted list.

Comment: Actually not completely true. iirc Java is using Timsort for some things starting with Java7 and Timsort is quite good at sorting partially sorted lists, i.e. better than the theoretical `O(n log n)`